# Software to provide loopback at remote endpoint, and client software to test performance

Tags: linux, networking

**NOTE**: I'm *not* looking at using the `lo` loopback network interface.

We're developing an embedded device that has its own internal Ethernet network, and a second network that is exposed to the outside world. The plan is to use SSH to tunnel through and access services on that internal network.

Does software exist that has a server part that simply accepts a connection and echoes everything back to the client, and a client part that simply crams data into the pipe and watches it come back, reporting on throughput, or at least simply loading the system so we can see what effect it has?

I had some difficulty searching the 'net for this, since "loopback" nearly always talks about the `lo` interface. I could implement myself, but if something already exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Echo Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol).

If your system is linux-based it's probably already available.

Else, should be trivial to program a simple echo server yourself.

Comment: That looks perfect, so the server side is taken care of. Now, just to find a client or write one. I'll accept if there isn't a better answer in about a day.